# Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

Tags: php, helper

i am making a helper file. But i get a Fatal Error at the beginning:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /pathtohelper/Helper/Data.php on line 2
```

My code:

```
    public  function getAvailableAttributesHelper($_product) {
$_product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

    if ($_product->getTypeId()=='configurable')
    {

    //Get Attributes
    $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product);
    if (count($attributes)) 
    {
        $html .= '<ul>';
        foreach($attributes as $att)
        { $pAtt=$_product->getProductAttribute();
         //get the child products
             $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
                $frontValues =array();
    $html .= '<ul>';
   $pAtt->getFrontendLabel();
$html .= '<ul>';
    foreach($allProducts as $p){
    //check stock, status, ...
    //do not show unsaleable options
    if(!$p->isSaleable()) continue;
    $out=$p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName());
    $frontValues[$out]=$out;
    }
    $html .= '<ul>';
     implode('</li><li>', $frontValues);
     $html .= '</li></ul></li>';}
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
      }
}
```

I have Magento 1.8.1 CE.

I also tried to replace line 2 en 3 with:

```
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
```

But with the same result.

The helper is from a custom theme.
Which is being used in

> `app\design\frontend\customtheme\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: where you  are using this helper function ?

Comment: Just updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mage::registry('current_product')** only work on `product details` page as per as default magento .This `registry variable is only  define at product view page`.

if you,want to get product id then you need to send current product object at function `getAvailableAttributesHelper.`

Just like

`Mage::helper('helper_Prefix')->getAvailableAttributesHelper($_product)`.

Also it is **very bad idea** to `load full product object ($_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load()` at  list page.It create issue in speed.

### Code may be like :

```
public  function getAvailableAttributesHelper($_product) {
$_product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

    if ($_product->getTypeId()=='configurable')
    {

    //Get Attributes
    $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product);
    if (count($attributes)) 
    {
        foreach($attributes as $att)
        { $pAtt=$_product->getProductAttribute();
         //get the child products
             $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
                $frontValues =array();
                 //<li>
                     $pAtt->getFrontendLabel();}
                 // CODE NOT FINISHED YET ...
        }
      }
      .....
}
```

### Update code like:

```
    public function getAvailableAttributesHelper($_product){
        $html='';
            if($_product->getTypeId()=='configurable'):
                $AllowAttributes=$_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product);
                     $skipSaleableCheck = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck();
                    $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)
                                    ->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
                    $option=array();
                    foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
// only show available option
                if(!$product->isSaleable()) continue;
                                foreach ($AllowAttributes as $attribute) {
                                        $productAttribute   = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                                        $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
                                            $option[$productAttribute->getAttributeCode()][]=$productAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                                }
                    }


                    $html='<ul>';
                    foreach($option  as $key=>$eachoption){
                            //array_unique($eachoption);
                            $html.='<li>'.$key.'<ul>';  
                            //print_r(array_unique($eachoption));
                                foreach(array_unique($eachoption) as $value){
                                    $html=$html.'<li>'.$value.'</li>';

                            }
                            $html.='</ul></li>';
                    }
                    $html.='</ul>';

            endif;
        return $html;
    }
```

Comment: I used your code, but now get a Fatal error on the 'getType' from line 4

Comment: sorry,it was mistake.it should be getTypeId

Comment: Still get a Error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getTypeId() on a non-object` but should the `$productObject` not be `$_product`?

Comment: i listed the full code .... (without the extra html marks)

Comment: please check...

Comment: Thx. I have no error's anymore ... Only i don't get an output too ... in the `list.phtml` is used `<?php echo Mage::helper('mymodule')->getAvailableAttributesHelper($_product) ?>` but without output. Do you see what is wrong?

Comment: wait, i will check

Comment: can you please tell me what is the target of your code.it will better to got solution.. there may be lot of issue in extension

Comment: I have the origional code from here: {link}(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950764/magento-how-to-show-configurable-product-options-in-product-list-page) This way i can show the available options of the configurable products on the product list page. This is a great wish for our shop. Only we have bought a theme for our store, and that theme generates the products from a helper .... thats why i now try to get this code working in the helper. If you want i could mail you the complete helper file and list.phtml file ...

Comment: Do you know what i am doing wrong, because it don't get any out .... not  even the html marks

Comment: i will check... on tomorrow

Comment: i will look on this on today

Comment: Do you want me to mail you the files?

Comment: I hope you will have time to check this for me today

Comment: i am checking ..

Comment: any luck checking?

Comment: please check this link http://inchoo.net/magento/display-multiple-configurable-products-with-options-on-one-page-in-magento/

Comment: But i only want to show the options in the list.phtml
The orginal code i had found does that for me, only due to my theme i have to code it in a helper file. The `if ($_product->getTypeId()=='configurable')` is false, even when it's is a configurable product

Answer (score 1):

you can pass product id as params to your helper like below

if you are override catalog data helper or you can add your own helper instead
in your

> `app\design\frontend\customtheme\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml`

```
Mage::helper('catalog')->getAvailableAttributesHelper($_product->getId());
```

and your function will be like

```
public function getAvailableAttributesHelper($productId) {

$_product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
.....
```

hope this will work for you.